# Copy configuration file on installation

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I am trying to package my Python project, which comes with a configuration dotfile that I want copied into the user's home directory on installation. The quick guide to packaging says that this can be done using the `data_files` argument to `setuptools.setup`. So this is what I have:

```
data_files = [(os.path.expanduser("~"), [".my_config"])]
```

This appears to work fine if I use `python setup.py install`, but when I upload my package to PyPI and run `pip install` the dotfile isn't copied.

FWIW, I've put the dotfile in the `MANIFEST.in` and also tried including the `package_data` argument to `setup`. None of these steps appear to make a difference. If I `pip install` and poke around the `site-packages` directory, just the source files are here.

How can I achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an issue I had once to experience myself. Its root is that when you are building a wheel file, all the absolute paths specified in `data_files` will be relativized to the target `site-packages` directory, see [this issue on github](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/issues/92). This influences installations performed by `pip install` as it will build a wheel out of any source package (`.tar.gz`, `.tar.bz2` or `.zip`) and install the resulting wheel:

```
$ pip install spam-0.1.tar.gz 
Processing ./spam-0.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: spam
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for spam ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/hoefling/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/d0/95/be/bc79f1d589d90d67139481a3e706bcc54578fdbf891aef75c0
Successfully built spam
Installing collected packages: spam
Successfully installed spam-0.1
```

Checking installed files yields:

```
$ pip show -f spam
Name: spam
Version: 0.1
...
Location: /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Files:
  Users/hoefling/.my_config
  spam-0.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  spam-0.1.dist-info/INSTALLER
  spam-0.1.dist-info/METADATA
  spam-0.1.dist-info/RECORD
  spam-0.1.dist-info/WHEEL
  spam-0.1.dist-info/metadata.json
  spam-0.1.dist-info/top_level.txt
```

Note the path meant to be absolute is relative to the `Location` dir. In the example, `.my_config` would be placed under `/Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Users/hoefling/.my_config`.

It gets even better because these built wheels are cached on your disk, so next time you reinstall the package and the built wheel still exists in `pip`'s cache, it will be used for the installation and you won't even see any mentions of building a wheel in the terminal log.

There is no real solution to avoid this. The most decent workaround I found is to prohibit "binary" packages when installing to enforce the execution of package's `setup.py` on installation:

```
$ pip install spam-0.1.tar.gz --no-binary=spam
Processing ./spam-0.1.tar.gz
Skipping bdist_wheel for spam, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: spam
  Running setup.py install for spam ... done
Successfully installed spam-0.1
```

The file is now placed correctly:

```
$ pip show -f spam
Name: spam
Version: 0.1
...
Location: /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Files:
  ../../../../../.my_config
  spam-0.1-py3.6.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  spam-0.1-py3.6.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
  spam-0.1-py3.6.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  spam-0.1-py3.6.egg-info/top_level.txt
```

Unfortunately, the user must be separately informed about calling `pip install` with the extra key (via readme, webpage FAQ or similar) as there is no possibility to prohibit building the wheel in package metadata.

As the result, I do not include files with absolute paths anymore. Instead, I install them with the python sources in the `site-packages` dir. In the python code, I have to add additional logic for the existence checks and file copying if necessary:

```python
# program entrypoint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.my_config')
    if not os.path.exists(config):
        shutil.copyfile('.my_config', config)
    main.run()
```

Comment: Thanks: I was thinking that adding the checking logic into the script would actually be safer, too, in case `pip` does the wrong thing when upgrading and silently overwrites any existing dotfile.

Comment: This is really a good answer and I wonder why it seems so few people run into this problem. Is it because there's so few package author?

Comment: @hoefling Is there a way to invoke such a copy operation for a library? Just putting it into the __init__.py? Since these posts are quite old, is there a newer approach to handle copy operations on installation?

Answer (score 4):

Besides what @hoefling said, I suggest you not using `data_files` at all! Because it's really unpredictable where the files will be copied to. You could test this by giving the directory something like `''`, `'/'`, or `'/anything/you/want'`.

I suggest you use `package_data` instead, which just copies the files under the distributed package root on installation. Then you can copy that to anywhere you want at run time.

For more on `package_data`, refer to Python Doc https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data

Comment: Another advantage of using `package_data` is an easy and OS-agnostic access to installed data files via `pkg_resources` API. I also prefer using `package_data` where possible. Good addition to the topic, upvoted!