# Proper way to copy configuration files during installation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, setuptools

I am trying to distribute a `mplstyle` I wrote such that I can share it easily. It boils down to copying a text file to the proper configuration direction (which is known for any architecture) during installation. I want to be able to install using either `python setup.py install` or `pip install ...`. Currently I do not seem to get either of the two ways robust (see current approach below).

- Installing with `pip install ...` does not seem to invoke the copying at all.
- Installing with `python setup.py install` works well on my machine, but ReadTheDocs gives me the following error:

  ```
  python setup.py install --force

  running install
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/docs/.config/matplotlib/stylelib/goose.mplsty
  ```

What is the proper way to copy configuration files during installation in a robust way?

## Current approach

### File structure

```
setup.py
goosempl/
| __init__.py
| stylelib/
  | goose.mplstyle
  | ...
```

### `setup.py`

```
from setuptools                 import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install

class PostInstallCommand(install):

  def run(self):

    import goosempl
    goosempl.copy_style()

    install.run(self)

setup(
  name              = 'goosempl',
  ...,
  install_requires  = ['matplotlib>=2.0.0'],
  packages          = ['goosempl'],
  cmdclass          = {'install': PostInstallCommand},
  package_data      = {'goosempl/stylelib':['goosempl/stylelib/goose.mplstyle']},
)
```

### `goosempl/__init__.py`

```
def copy_style():

  import os
  import matplotlib

  from pkg_resources import resource_string

  files = [
    'stylelib/goose.mplstyle',
  ]

  for fname in files:
    path = os.path.join(matplotlib.get_configdir(),fname)
    text = resource_string(__name__,fname).decode()

    print(path, text)

    open(path,'w').write(text)
```

### Upload to PyPi

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
twine upload dist/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, based on the project structure you've provided, you're not specifying the `package_data` correctly. If `goosempl` is a package and `stylelib` a directory inside it containing the `mplstyle` files (what I assume from your code), then your `package_data` configuration line should be:

```
package_data = {'goosempl': ['stylelib/goose.mplstyle']},
```

As described in [Building and Distributing Packages with Setuptools](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files):

> The `package_data` argument is a dictionary that maps from package names to lists of glob patterns. The globs may include subdirectory names, if the data files are contained in a subdirectory of the package.

So your package is `goosempl` and `stylelib/goose.mplstyle` is the file to be included in package data for `goosempl`.

Your second issue (`No such file or directory`) is simple: in the `copy_style()` function, you never check if the parent directory of the file exists before writing the file. You should be able to reproduce this locally by removing the directory `/home/<user>/.config/matplotlib/stylelib/` (or moving it temporarily).

The fix is also quite simple, actually there are lots of them. Use whatever you want to create missing directories.

- [`distutils.dir_util.mkpath`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.mkpath) is suitable for both `python2` and `python3`:

  ```
  for fname in files:
      path = os.path.join(matplotlib.get_configdir(), fname)
      distutils.dir_util.mkpath(os.dirname(path))
  ```
- My preferred one is using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), but it is available only since Python 3.4:

  ```
  for fname in files:
      path = pathlib.Path(matplotlib.get_configdir(), fname)
      path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this solves most of my problems. I used `os` in the end: `if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(path)): os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path))` (notice the small bug on my side). It does not, however, seem to fix the problem with pip. Installing from PyPi with pip does not seems to invoke the `PostInstallCommand` command. (It is only invoked on my machine before uploading to PyPi).

Comment: The `install` command won't be invoked by `pip`. It does not install from source by design. Instead, it builds a wheel and installs from it - but `wheel` format does not use the setup script - it does not even include it. So your `PostInstallCommand` won't be called.

Comment: OK, I understand. Is there a way to copy these configuration files upon installing with `pip`? I understand that one can just include the copying command such that it is always invoked upon including the library, but this is really not what I am looking for as (i) this results in unnecessary checks that are run over and over, and (ii) in my particular case I want users to load the style, without ever needed to include the library.

Comment: Unfortunately, in your case there isn't - you want to place the file outside of the `site-packages` directory, and `wheel` doesn't allow that. See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47465374/2650249) to a similar question - the OP wanted to place a config file in the user's home dir on installation. The only workaround for that is not to build wheels in first place, building a source tar/zip/bz2 instead, and on installation tell `pip` not to build a wheel out of source distribution with the `--no-binary` flag.