# Copy dlls from a python wheel into folder during installation

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-poetry, python-wheel

I would like to build a python wheel package that includes some dlls. When I install that package the dlls should be copied to specific directory relativ to the python path.

I looked through poetry and setuptools documentation but did not find anything yet.
The only thing I've found is this ([Proper way to copy configuration files during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084864/proper-way-to-copy-configuration-files-during-installation)), but the answers are quite old. Is this still the way of doing it or is there a newer approach?