# Install into ~/.config dir

Tags: python, installation, setuptools

I would like to install a config file in a users `.config` directory. I've tried

```py
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup
import os

setup(
  # ...
  data_files=[(
    '{}/.config/foobar/'.format(os.environ['HOME']), 
    ['config/foobar.config']
  )]
)
```

but this strips the leading `/` and installs the file at

```
$HOME/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/home/johndoe/.config/foobar/foobar.config
```

How to install into the ~/.config dir? Bonus points if it works with a `setup.cfg` file.

Comment: If pip installation would be able to write to absolute paths at install time, it would be quite a big security hole.  I'd personally consider doing that the bootstrap phase of your code by checking if the foobar/foobar.config exists before it is loaded and write it then ..

Comment: I'd also have to check if the contents are equal, for updates. This is less than ideal.

Comment: Check out [Copy configuration file on installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47460804/2650249). tl;dr: don't try copying files outside of site dir on installation. Instead, install new config template, check whether current config is up to date on program start, if not, copy new config over.